# JavaScript String.raw to not process substitutions to get the "raw" raw string?

Tags: javascript, escaping, template-literals

I'd like to use a user provided string as argument for a JavaScript function and hence need to escape all characters that could cause the script to break.

This is for a Swift to JavaScript bridge to be used with `WKWebView.evaluateJavaScript()` that processes raw JavaScript.

```
window.someObject.method( ... user provided string ... )
```

The string can contain anything, line breaks, double quotes, backticks, unicode escape sequenced, substitutions, etc.

Currently I use a template literal and escape:

- \ with \\ (single backslash with double backslash)
- ${ with \${
- ` with backslash+backtick

I'm trying to get this to work with `String.raw`, but I cannot figure out how to escape substitutions.

Potential user input:

```
hello ${1+1}
```

I want that exact string as argument to my JavaScript function, no substitutions being processed.

Here is what I tried:

```js
// User input is: hello ${1+1}
console.log(String.raw`hello ${1+1}`)
console.log(String.raw`hello \${1+1}`) // So close, but not quite

console.log('I want: hello ${1+1}')
```

What I want is this:

```
window.someObject.method( String.raw`hello ${1+1}` ) → hello ${1+1}
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: How does the user's string get to the Javascript? Is it written directly into Javascript in the HTML at the moment?

Comment: No, the String is actually a JSON string generated by a Swift API. I then generate a JavaScript snippet on the fly and inject it into the page by calling `webView.evaluateJavaScript()` so the JavaScript is parsed and evaluated.

Comment: Well, don't use `String.raw` at all. Just JavaScript-encode the string (similar to JSON-encoding a string value)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
/**
 * Prepare multi-line string for inclusion in JavaScript.
 * 
 * Note! New line characters are added because slash (\) at the end of template string would brake template syntax.
 * Starting new line is added for code beauty ;-).
 * 
 * @param {String} text Some string.
 */
prepareTemplateString(text) {
    if (text.search(/[`$]/)>=0) {
        text = text.replace(/([`$])/g, '\\$1');
        return "String.raw`\n"+text+"\n`.replace(/\\\\([`$])/g, '\\$1')";
    }
    return "String.raw`\n"+text+"\n`";
}
```

But I'm not happy with that. It seems that `String.raw` is actually slower then standard template string. I thought there would be some optimizations for String.raw but it seems it's just another layer on top of template strings.